# Laravel's signedURL generates wrong URL when using api middlware

Tags: laravel, api, signed-url

I have a front-end running on Nuxt and Laravel as a back-end service. When I generate the signedURL using the Laravel's API middleware - the path includes "api" in the URL, resulting into a page not found exception on the Nuxt side

So, here are the steps to better understand what's happening:

1. User clicks a button in Nuxt application and sends the ajax request to the Laravel API
2. API Controller generates the signedURL

`$signedUrl = URL::signedRoute('register', ['email' => $this->request->email, 'group_id' => $this->request->group_id], null, false);`

3. Generated URL includes the "api" in the path, which of course, cannot be accessed
   `http://localhost:3000/api/register?email=ss%40gmail.com&group_id=2&signature=ce4fba05bf5ccae6ea20a6043a47ca11de603238214deda7202d19f2989272cb`

Is there a way to get rid of the /api/ from the generated URL? I've tried setting 4th param (absolute) in the method signedRoute to false, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Can you share your router for the `'register'` route ?

Comment: Sue, here it is, under routes/api
`Route::get('register', 'RegisterController@register')->name('register');
 
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');`

Comment: The api default routes have prefix 'api' so when you generate the signed URL, you are requesting the route `register`, therefore the generated URL will be `www.mydomain.com/api/register?...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default api routes have prefix 'api' as seen in your RouterProvider:

```
    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
               ...;
    }
```

When you generate the signed URL, for your route `'register'` which is using the prefix `api` , the generated URL will be as expected: `www.mydomain.com/api/register?...`